# What is the precise relation between the eigenvalues of a covariance *function* and the eigenvalues of a covariance *matrix*?

Tags: pca, covariance, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process, eigenvalues

Assume we have a temporal Gaussian Process $\mathcal{GP}(t;\ m,k)$ (GP) with mean $m$ and covariance function (aka. kernel) $k$ on some compact time interval $[0,T]$. Then, the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and eigenfunctions $\phi$ of k are, for a pre-defined measure $\mu$, defined as the solution of the Fredholm integral equation, written

$$ \int k(t,t^{\prime}) \phi(t)\ \mathrm{d} \mu(t) = \lambda \phi(t^{\prime}). $$

See eq. (4.36) in [1] for more details.

I am interested in how the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, relate to the eigenvalues of a corresponding covariance matrix $K \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ for some fixed times $0 \leq t_1 \leq \dots \leq t_N \leq T$, with entries

$$ K_{ij} = k(t_i, t_j)$$

coming from evaluations of this same cov function $k$.

I suspect that there is a strong connections between the eigenvalues of the cov function $k$ and the cov matrix $K$ for the following reason: The wikipedia article on the Karhunen-Loeve theorem, which makes use of the eigenvalues of the cov function $k$ [2], somehow is related to the eigenvalues in PCA [3], that is to the eigenvalues of the cov matrix $K$. Unfortunately, I do not understand the explanation in [3]. Therefore I am asking the question here on what the relation between these function and matrix eigenproblem is.

As a pointer, a colleague told me to look at the equivalent kernel (Section 7.1 in [1]) which apparently describes how GP regression behaves in the limit of continuous data [4], i.e. if $N \to \infty$. I can intuitively see how this might relate the above function eigenproblem to the matrix eigenproblem, but I could not find any explicit statement on such a relation.

Thank you :)

[1] http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf
[2] [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen–Loève_theorem#Formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem#Formulation)
[3] [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen–Loève_theorem#Covariance_matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem#Covariance_matrix)
[4] https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2004/file/d89a66c7c80a29b1bdbab0f2a1a94af8-Paper.pdf

Comment: See Chap 2 of [Limin Wang's Phd](http://etheses.lse.ac.uk/2950/) which I find very clear.

Comment: Thanks! I skim-read Chap 2, it is a detailed investigation of numerical methods of to compute the Karhunen-Loeve expansion. But I could not find a relation with covariance matrices in it. Are you sure this is the correct chapter?

Comment: Well, the approximation holds only when the design points $t_i$ are dense enough. Roughly speaking, the mean of the Dirac measures $N^{-1} \sum_i \delta_{t_i}$ should be close to $\mu$. This is achived with quadrature points.